# Extend the options of LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I would like to be able to write the following in a LINQ query:

```
from item in list
collate by item.Property
select item;
```

to use this code, I have the following method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CollateBy<T,TKey>(
                                 this IEnumerable<T> arr, 
                                 Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
{
    foreach (var group in arr.GroupBy(keySelector))
    {
        foreach (var item in group)
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

How do I write this method so that the query stated above would work?

Comment: You would need to modify the compiler :-) Note that the "query" words used in the query syntax are actual keywords which the compiler knows and understands how to translate/map them into "method syntax". (Also see C# language spec, section 12.17.3 Query expression translation https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) Note that there are also disucssions on roslyn's (= c# compiler platform) GitHub page about expanding query syntax. Not sure if some of the discussions relate to your desire, though...

Comment: If you want to change the syntax of the language, take Nemerle. This language, thanks to metaprogramming and macros, allows you to enter new keywords.

Comment: Since your `Collate` is equivalent to a `GroupBy` and then a `SelectMany` it can be done with `from item in list group item by item.Property into grp from x in grp select x`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this. `from`, `in`, `by` and `select` are C# [keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/). So that you ask is equivalent to define a custom keyword, which is not possible.

For the record, each LINQ query written in query syntax (like the one you have mentioned) under the hood is compiled in method calls that have the same result.

For instance the following query:

```
var adultCustomers = from customer in customers
                     where customer.Age > 18;
```

is equivalent to the query below:

```
var adultCustomers = customers.Where(customer=>customer.Age>18);
```

Under the hood the compiler initially translates the first query to the second one. The first version is just syntactic sugar.

In your case the following query (method syntax) is might that you want:

```
var result = list.CollateBy(item => item.Property);
```

Comment: I understand the code equivalence you stated, but the first is more readable; I would like to use a similarly readable form for collating items.

Comment: Unfortunately, something like this I don't think that's possible, as I have already mentioned it. However, I will state that this `list.CollateBy(item=>item.Property)` is seems more readable, but this is my personal preference in this specific case and by no means that you should find it more readable comparing it with the corresponding query syntax.

Comment: @EliFalk I agree with Christos. I’ve been working as a .NET developer for the past decade. I almost never see query syntax because it’s just not as readable and sort of weird considering the rest of the language. Method syntax is more useable and extendable, prettier (in mine and most people I knows eyes) and it just fits in with the rest of the language features better.